# TreeView's scroll jumps to top the first time a node is expanded

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, treeview, scrollviewer

The first time I expand a node in my `TreeView`, the `TreeView`'s `ScrollViewer` jumps the scroll to the top.  After this initial jump, the `TreeView`'s scroll behaves as expected.

How can I prevent this behavior?

I've tried setting `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` on the `TreeView`, and I've even tried doing strange things like calling `ScrollToTop()` on the `TreeView`'s `ScrollViewer` in the `Loaded` callback to see if I could trigger some kind of initialization that's not happening otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean "After this initial jump, the TreeView's scroll behaves as expected."

Comment: After I expand one node (and the scroll of the `TreeView` jumps to the top), I can expand nodes without experiencing this jumping behavior (for the rest of the lifetime of the `TreeView`).

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a custom style for expander toggle button, with property 'Focusable' set to False. That caused TreeView scroll jump to selected item when user expands something in the tree. Solution - Focusable="True"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same situation and the below solved this for me. In the code behind, after your tree view items have been created do the following:

```
TreeViewItem item = this.TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as TreeViewItem;
if (item != null)
{
    item.IsSelected = true;
    item.Focus();
}
```